# How to achieve a staggered grid layout using Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose

As far as I can see we can only use `Rows` and `Columns` in `Jetpack Compose` to show lists. How can I achieve a staggered grid layout like the image below? The normal implementation of it using a `Recyclerview` and a staggered grid layout manager is pretty easy. But how to do the same in Jetpack Compose ?

[image]

Comment: try this
https://github.com/nesyou01/LazyStaggeredGrid

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of Google's Compose sample [Owl](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Owl) shows how to do a staggered grid layout. This is the code snippet that is used to compose this:

```
@Composable
fun StaggeredVerticalGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    maxColumnWidth: Dp,
    children: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        children = children,
        modifier = modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        check(constraints.hasBoundedWidth) {
            "Unbounded width not supported"
        }
        val columns = ceil(constraints.maxWidth / maxColumnWidth.toPx()).toInt()
        val columnWidth = constraints.maxWidth / columns
        val itemConstraints = constraints.copy(maxWidth = columnWidth)
        val colHeights = IntArray(columns) { 0 } // track each column's height
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            val column = shortestColumn(colHeights)
            val placeable = measurable.measure(itemConstraints)
            colHeights[column] += placeable.height
            placeable
        }

        val height = colHeights.maxOrNull()?.coerceIn(constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight)
                ?: constraints.minHeight
        layout(
                width = constraints.maxWidth,
                height = height
        ) {
            val colY = IntArray(columns) { 0 }
            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                val column = shortestColumn(colY)
                placeable.place(
                        x = columnWidth * column,
                        y = colY[column]
                )
                colY[column] += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun shortestColumn(colHeights: IntArray): Int {
    var minHeight = Int.MAX_VALUE
    var column = 0
    colHeights.forEachIndexed { index, height ->
        if (height < minHeight) {
            minHeight = height
            column = index
        }
    }
    return column
}
```

And then you can pass in your item composable in it:

```
StaggeredVerticalGrid(
    maxColumnWidth = 220.dp,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
) {
    // Use your item composable here
}
```

Link to snippet in the sample: https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/1630f6b35ac9e25fb3cd3a64208d7c9afaaaedc5/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/example/owl/ui/courses/FeaturedCourses.kt#L161

Comment: Does anyone know how to make this implementation Lazy? For 100s of items, it will get very heavy

Comment: does it recycle ?

Comment: No, it's not able to recycle

Comment: Grid Not Working , Try This : Replace item Constraints with `val itemConstraints = constraints.copy(minWidth = 0,maxWidth = columnWidth)`                   You can center horizontally if you plus             `if(horizontalAlignment==Alignment.CenterHorizontally) (columnWidth - placeable.width) / 2 else 0`      in placeable.place method in x

Comment: but it's just for ordinal lists, in real apps we would use paging data

Comment: @AhmadSattout you can use LazyLayout but there is no example or documentation yet!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this answer is misleading because it is does not produce the staggered gridlayout of recyclerview which is what was requested in the question. It does not scroll!

Answer (score 9):

It's now available in version 1.3.0-beta02. You can implement it like this:

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
) {
    itemsIndexed((0..50).toList()) { i, item ->
        Box(
            Modifier
                .padding(2.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(20.dp * i)
                .background(Color.Cyan),
        )
    }
}
```

Or you can use horizontal view `LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid`

Comment: works fine, and can be used with paging list

Answer (score 4):

Your layout is a scrollable layout with rows of multiple cards (2 or 4)

The row with 2 items :

```
@Composable
fun GridRow2Elements(row: RowData) {
  Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
  ) {
    GridCard(row.datas[0], small = true, endPadding = 0.dp)
    GridCard(row.datas[1], small = true, startPadding = 0.dp)
  } 
}
```

The row with 4 items :

```
@Composable
fun GridRow4Elements(row: RowData) {
 Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
 ) {
    Column {
        GridCard(row.datas[0], small = true, endPadding = 0.dp)
        GridCard(row.datas[1], small = false, endPadding = 0.dp)
    }
    Column {
        GridCard(row.datas[2], small = false, startPadding = 0.dp)
        GridCard(row.datas[3], small = true, startPadding = 0.dp)
    }
 }
}
```

The final grid layout :

```
@Composable
fun Grid(rows: List<RowData>) {
ScrollableColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    rows.mapIndexed { index, rowData ->
        if (rowData.datas.size == 2) {
            GridRow2Elements(rowData)
        } else if (rowData.datas.size == 4) {
            GridRow4Elements(rowData)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Then, you can customize with the card layout you want . I set static values for small and large cards (120, 270 for height and 170 for width)

```
@Composable
fun GridCard(
 item: Item,
 small: Boolean,
 startPadding: Dp = 8.dp,
 endPadding: Dp = 8.dp,
) {
 Card(
    modifier = Modifier.preferredWidth(170.dp)
        .preferredHeight(if (small) 120.dp else 270.dp)
        .padding(start = startPadding, end = endPadding, top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
) {
 ...
}
```

I transformed the datas in :

```
data class RowData(val datas: List<Item>)
data class Item(val text: String, val imgRes: Int)
```

You simply have to call it with

```
 val listOf2Elements = RowData(
    listOf(
        Item("Zesty Chicken", xx),
        Item("Spring Rolls", xx),
    )
)

val listOf4Elements = RowData(
    listOf(
        Item("Apple Pie", xx),
        Item("Hot Dogs", xx),
        Item("Burger", xx),
        Item("Pizza", xx),
    )
)

Grid(listOf(listOf2Elements, listOf4Elements))
```

Sure you need to manage carefully your data transformation because you can have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with data[index]

Answer (score 4):

Starting from [**`1.3.0-beta02`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.3.0-beta02) you can use the **`LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid`**.

Something like:

```
    val state = rememberLazyStaggeredGridState()

    LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
        columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        state = state,
        content = {

            items(count) {
                //item content
            }
        }
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems like added recently as per the developer site. But i am not able to refer to it in Android studio despite adding the beta version. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

This library will help you [LazyStaggeredGrid](https://github.com/nesyou01/LazyStaggeredGrid)

Usage:

```
LazyStaggeredGrid(cells = StaggeredCells.Adaptive(minSize = 180.dp)) {
     items(60) {
        val randomHeight: Double = 100 + Math.random() * (500 - 100)
          Image(
             painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.image),
             contentDescription = null,
             modifier = Modifier.height(randomHeight.dp).padding(10.dp),
             contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
          )
      }
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The columns are scrolled independently. This is not how it works in RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid`

Follow this steps

> Step 1 Add the below dependency in your `build.gradle` file

```
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.3.0-rc01"
```

> Step 2 import the below classes in your activity file

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.StaggeredGridCells
```

> Step 3 Add `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` like this

```
  LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
    state = state,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    content = {
      val list = listOf(1,2,4,3,5,6,8,8,9)
      items(list.size) { position ->
        Box(
          Modifier.padding(5.dp)
        ) {
          // create your own layout here
          NotesItem(list[position])
        }
      }
    })
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote custom staggered column
feel free to use it:

```
@Composable
fun StaggerdGridColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    columns: Int = 3,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(content = content, modifier = modifier) { measurables, constraints ->
        val columnWidths = IntArray(columns) { 0 }
        val columnHeights = IntArray(columns) { 0 }

        val placables = measurables.mapIndexed { index, measurable ->
            val placable = measurable.measure(constraints)

            val col = index % columns
            columnHeights[col] += placable.height
            columnWidths[col] = max(columnWidths[col], placable.width)
            placable
        }

        val height = columnHeights.maxOrNull()
            ?.coerceIn(constraints.minHeight.rangeTo(constraints.maxHeight))
            ?: constraints.minHeight

        val width =
            columnWidths.sumOf { it }.coerceIn(constraints.minWidth.rangeTo(constraints.maxWidth))

        val colX = IntArray(columns) { 0 }
        for (i in 1 until columns) {
            colX[i] = colX[i - 1] + columnWidths[i - 1]
        }

        layout(width, height) {
            val colY = IntArray(columns) { 0 }
            placables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                val col = index % columns
                placeable.placeRelative(
                    x = colX[col],
                    y = colY[col]
                )
                colY[col] += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using side:

```
Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {

    val size = remember {
        mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                size.value = it.size
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
    ) {
        val columns = 3
        StaggerdGridColumn(
            columns = columns
        ) {
            topics.forEach {
                Chip(
                    text = it,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { (size.value.width / columns).toDp() })
                        .padding(8.dp),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun Chip(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, text: String) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
        border = BorderStroke(color = Color.Black, width = 1.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        elevation = 10.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, top = 4.dp, end = 8.dp, bottom = 4.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(16.dp, 16.dp)
                    .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = text,
                style = TextStyle(color = Color.DarkGray, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about lazy column with paging data? it's only for usual lists

Answer (score 0):

Really saved a lot of time thanks guys(author of answers). I tried all 3 ways.

This is not an answer rather an observation. For me order of items were not maintained for answer#1[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64256721/16387867). For sample list it did , but with actual list in office work it did not. ordering was altered by one position. I tried even with array list, input list were ordered but views were displaced still.

However, answer#2[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69676431/16387867) did maintained order. And works correctly. I am using this one.
answer#3[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878940/16387867) did worked as expected as both columns have their individual and independent scroll behaviour

Note: Pagination is still not supported in any of the custom implementation. Manual observation on last item is required to trigger fetching new data. (we can't use pager from pager library, there's no way to make call on pager obj.  However, there is manual paging in 'start' code of advance paging codelab (manual paging works there in sample)) https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#0
Cheers folks.!!

**UPDATE with working answer**

Please go thorough [Android jetpack compose pagination : Pagination not working with staggered layout jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276953/android-jetpack-compose-pagination-pagination-not-working-with-staggered-layou/73453994#73453994) , Where I have working sample of staggered layout in compose and also with supporting pagination.

Solution : https://github.com/rishikumr/stackoverflow_code_sharing/tree/main/staggered-layout-compose-with_manual_pagination

Working video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IsKy0wzbyqI3dme3x7rzrZ6uHZZE9jrL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is better to comment on the answers to the question and up/down vote them, then to formulate a new answer.

Comment: I understand and that should be right way. I just don't have enough reputations. Also, I managed to get working staggered layout with pagination. I will post a solution with pagination real soon.

Comment: @user924 was your comment a lot in every places looking for answer with pagination support. Please check this , let me know if it helped. :))