# How to fill row nested in lazycolumn. JetpacCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I make my own and very simple calendar.
Problem: I'm trying to display values ​​from a list. There are seven values ​​in one line. Each new line continues the list.
Below is an example of invalid code. But he shows the essence and the problem)

```
          //.....
          LazyColumn (
            modifier = Modifier,
            content = {
                items(7) { row ->
                    Row {
                        for(n in 0..6){Text("${weeks1[n]}")}
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```

output:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1IE4.png)

So i need to display list items like:

- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
- 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
- 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want but you can try this :

```
val dates = MutableList(31) { it }

LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .systemBarsPadding(),
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(7),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    items(dates) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Text(text = "${it + 1}")
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :

[image: Result dates]

**Update with alternative solution**

A solution with LazyColumn and Row with the same result (more difficult to achieve, less elegant)

```
val dates = MutableList(35) { if (it + 1 > 31) -1 else it + 1 }
val chunks = dates.chunked(7)

LazyColumn(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .systemBarsPadding()
) {
    items(chunks) {
        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            it.forEach { date ->
                Box(Modifier.size(24.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                    if (date != -1) Text(text = "$date")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, ty for answer. But i have list with values. I want to display them. In you'r example line #2 need to containe: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
line #3 containe: 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 and etc.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, I updated my answer

Comment: thanks for helping and you'r patience. i try this example before. the problem with this method is that it is not flexible enough. How can I do the same but using only LazyColumn and Row.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative solution but it's more difficult to achieve than the first solution with LazyVerticalGrid

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using `staggered grid layout`. One of Google's Compose sample [Owl](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/example/owl/ui/onboarding/Onboarding.kt#L239) shows how to do a staggered grid layout. Also you can go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237442/how-to-achieve-a-staggered-grid-layout-using-jetpack-compose).