# Tag list with Jetpack Compose on Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create Composable like this:
[image]

I tried to use **LazyVerticalGrid** with **GridCells.Adaptive(100.dp)** but width of elements is fixed (100dp).
I need to have width of the element different for different text length and be able to see different amount of tags on a different cols of my grid.

Comment: Take the layout codelab. It extensively covers this very thing. Airways read the docs before posting here.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper I googled for it and wasn't able to find answer, watched youtube, read docs for lazyGrids, but didn't find the answer. Codelabs gives only simple examples with rectangles having the same width. If you know codelab for my problem, can you give the link or at least the exact name?

Comment: When I took the codelab about a year or so ago, it had your use-case implemented as far as I can remember. They updated the codelabs entirely in the August of 2022. Must have been deemed too advanced, or too specific for a codelab, and so it might have been removed. But I'll try to find a stackoverflow link to a question dealing with the same issue. I'm sure I saw one here as well.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64237442/15880865 and also, here's a relaxing piece to help you focus/unwind - https://youtu.be/0Q4aXNx8C4c

Comment: What you're looking for is called a Staggered Grid.

Comment: Just search the term on google and you'll have a truckload of results for all platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FlowRow` from [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist).

```
FlowRow(
    mainAxisSpacing = 16.dp,
) {
    // The Tag Composable comes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works the way I need it :)