# what create LazyVerticalGrid or grid with irregular number cells for row in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

what create in jetpack compose a LazyVerticalGrid or Grid with irregular number cells for row??? for example

[image]

Comment: If it is either n columns or 1 column (for header), you can use `item(span = {GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)})` for the header item as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-grids).

Comment: Another composable very dynamic item width is `FlowRow` from Accompanist.

Comment: If your use case is neither of the above, kindly add more details.

Comment: It is impossible, i dont't understand,     Item  (span =)   required "compose_version = '1.3.0-beta01'" and  this version compose require API 33 , but when you configure this API , project crash

Comment: Search the web for "Staggered Grid in Jetpack Compose"

Comment: resolved. thanks to all

Comment: @iqanansoft check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080056/7666442

Answer (score 0):

solution ... i use a "Stagger Vertical Grid" , this isn't a component  jetpack compose so it should be created

First step. create this class or similar...

```
  fun StaggeredVerticalGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    maxColumnWidth: Dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val placeableXY: MutableMap<Placeable, Pair<Int, Int>> = mutableMapOf()

        check(constraints.hasBoundedWidth) {
            "Unbounded width not supported"
        }
    val columns = ceil(constraints.maxWidth / maxColumnWidth.toPx()).toInt()
    val columnWidth = constraints.maxWidth / columns
    val itemConstraints = constraints.copy(maxWidth = columnWidth)
    val colHeights = IntArray(columns) { 0 } // track each column's height
    val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
        val column = shortestColumn(colHeights)
        val placeable = measurable.measure(itemConstraints)
        placeableXY[placeable] = Pair(columnWidth * column, colHeights[column])
        colHeights[column] += placeable.height
        placeable
    }

    val height = colHeights.maxOrNull()
        ?.coerceIn(constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight)
        ?: constraints.minHeight
    layout(
        width = constraints.maxWidth,
        height = height
    ) {
        placeables.forEach { placeable ->
            placeable.place(
                x = placeableXY.getValue(placeable).first,
                y = placeableXY.getValue(placeable).second
            )
        }
    }
}
}

private fun shortestColumn(colHeights: IntArray): Int {
    var minHeight = Int.MAX_VALUE
    var column = 0
    colHeights.forEachIndexed { index, height ->
        if (height < minHeight) {
            minHeight = height
            column = index
        }
    }
    return column
}
```

second step. create into lazycolumn this code , or similar

```
LazyColumn(....){
        items(){.....ANother items lazy column......}
        item{
              val columnWidth =remember {mutableStateOf((50..220).random())}
              StaggeredVerticalGrid(
                         maxColumnWidth = columnWidth.value.dp,
                         modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
               ){
                (1..300).forEach {
        Text(it.toString(),modifier=Modifier.width(columnWidth.value.dp))
                         }
                }
    
    }
    items(){..ANother items lazy column...}
    }
```

Example code https://github.com/elye/demo_android_jetpack_compose_staggered_vertical_grid/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/staggerdverticalgrid/MainActivity.kt

Another example "Stagger Vertical Grid" is

[How to achieve a staggered grid layout using Jetpack compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237442/how-to-achieve-a-staggered-grid-layout-using-jetpack-compose)